# process vm readv fails after certain number of iovec in MPI

Tags: mpi, openmpi, dma

I'm using process_vm_readv to get data from one process to the other in MPI.
I found the program will start getting trash after certain number of iovec (in this case 1024) given to process_vm_readv.
I wasn't sure what is going on, did the kernel running out of memory? Or something wrong with in my code.
Or did process_vm_readv has a upper limit for iovec?
I self-generated a vector pattern (8 bytes out of every 16 bytes) for iovec.
And the program will run until 1GB is filled with this pattern on both threads.
sbuf and rbuf have been allocated each for 1GB of memory.
And the program sits on a 24GB+ machine.

```
void do_test( int slen, int rlen, int scount, int rcount, void *sbuf, void *rbuf ){
int rank, err;
double timers[REP];
MPI_Win win;
pid_t pid;

MPI_Comm_rank( MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank );
if( rank == 0 ){
    MPI_Win_create( NULL, 0, 1, MPI_INFO_NULL, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &win );

    int send_iovcnt;
    struct iovec *send_iov;

    struct iovec *iov = malloc( sizeof(struct iovec) * scount );
    for( int p = 0; p < scount; p++ ){
        iov[p].iov_base = (char*)rbuf + p * 16;
        iov[p].iov_len = 8;
    }

    MPI_Recv( &pid, sizeof(pid_t), MPI_BYTE, 1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE );
    MPI_Recv( &send_iovcnt, 1, MPI_INT, 1, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE );

    send_iov = malloc( sizeof(struct iovec) * send_iovcnt );

    MPI_Recv( send_iov, sizeof(struct iovec) * send_iovcnt, MPI_BYTE, 1, 2, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE );
    for( int i = 0; i < REP; i++ ){
        cache_flush();
        timers[i] = MPI_Wtime();
        MPI_Win_fence( 0, win );
        process_vm_readv( pid, iov, send_iovcnt, send_iov, send_iovcnt, 0 );
        MPI_Win_fence( 0, win );
        cache_flush();
        timers[i] = MPI_Wtime() - timers[i];
    }
    free(send_iov);
    free(iov);

    print_result( 8 * scount, REP, timers );
} else if( rank == 1 ){
    MPI_Win_create( sbuf, slen, 1, MPI_INFO_NULL, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &win );

    struct iovec *iov = malloc( sizeof(struct iovec) * rcount );

    for( int p = 0; p < rcount; p++ ){
        iov[p].iov_base = (char*)sbuf + p * 16;
        iov[p].iov_base = 8;
    }

    pid = getpid();
    MPI_Send( &pid, sizeof(pid_t), MPI_BYTE, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD );
    MPI_Send( &rcount, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD );
    MPI_Send( iov, rcount * sizeof(struct iovec), MPI_BYTE, 0, 2, MPI_COMM_WORLD );
    for( int i = 0; i < REP; i++ ){
        cache_flush();
        MPI_Win_fence( 0, win );
        MPI_Win_fence( 0, win );
    }
    free(iov);

}
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why are you mixing a portable API such as MPI with Linux-speicific system calls? MPI provides its own set of portable calls that allow one rank to access directly the memory of another one. If you need to exchange information quickly between ranks on the same node, just expose shared-memory windows.

Comment: Exactly. MPI_Win_allocate_shared obviates the need for this.

Comment: it's just experiment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found in the [man page of `process_vm_readv(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/process_vm_readv.2.html) is the following text:

> The values specified in the `liovcnt` and `riovcnt` arguments must be less than or equal to `IOV_MAX` (defined in `<limits.h>` or accessible via the call `sysconf(_SC_IOV_MAX)`).

On my Linux system, the value of `IOV_MAX` (ultimately defined in `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/uio_lim.h`) is 1024.

Comment: is there a way to set it to IOV_MAX to other values?

Comment: No. The value is hardcoded in the Linux kernel source code in `include/uapi/linux/uio.h`. In theory, you may be able to build your own kernel with higher value, but that would only work for you and it isn't clear what assumptions will break.